# CSS : When to use display flex and display inline-block?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

[image]

Hi, I have a scenario in which i want to make the above view. I am using `Bootstrap4` and I know I can achieve this by using either `display:flex` or `display:inline-block`. Now I really wanna know which to use when ? What's the best practice ?

Right now i am doing something like this.

```css
.job-details-container {
  display: flex;
}

.job-details-container .job-details-type {
  width: 15%
}
```

```html
<div class="job-details-container">
    <div class="job-details-type">Id</div>
    <div class="job-details-content">0234</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use bootstrap 4 use `row` and `col` then you do not have to worry about dispaly type

Comment: your data is in table form, just use a table.

Comment: I would simply use a table because your data is in table format, If it was one line vertical or horizontal then i would use flex with flex-wrap

Comment: I also suggest to use the table or bootstrap row col.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is essentially a table. So I suggest using HTML tables. The cells will stretch automatically just like with `flex`. Tables are fully supported back to IE 8.

```css
.job-details {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="job-details">
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>0234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service Type</td>
    <td>Move</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Schedule</td>
    <td>11:00 am, Jan 1, 2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Change to `flex` if you want to create layouts and complex designs. For displaying simple text or maybe some images, tables are your friends.